# d2i_RSA_PUBKEY, d2i_RSAPrivateKey and d2i_RSAPublicKey returns NULL

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I created a RSA private key using the following command:

```
 openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048
```

I must to use DER-encoded keys (PKCS#1) for this project, so I generated two DER files from this PEM-encoded private key file - one with the private key and another with the public key.

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -in keypair.pem -outform DER -pubout -out public.der

openssl rsa -inform PEM -in keypair.pem -outform DER -out private.der
```

In my code, I loaded the contents of both these files in char* variables.

None of the following works as expected:

```
d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
```

I know that beacause all of them return `null`. I also tried the following:

```
RSA * rsa = RSA_new();
d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

RSA * rsa = RSA_new();
d2i_RSAPublicKey(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

RSA * rsa = RSA_new();
d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&rsa, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
```

All return `null` as well.

My complete test code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

typedef struct
{
    int len;
    char * bytes;
} FileData;

static FileData readFileBytes(const char * name, int zero_ended)
{
    FILE * fl = fopen(name, "r");
    if (fl == NULL) return (FileData) { .len = 0, .bytes = NULL };
    fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END);
    long len = ftell(fl);
    char * ret = malloc(len + (zero_ended ? 1 : 0));
    fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(ret, 1, len, fl);
    if (zero_ended) ret[len] = 0;
    fclose(fl);
    return (FileData) { .len = len, .bytes = ret };
}

int main()
{
    FileData private_key = readFileBytes("../private.der", 0);
    FileData public_key = readFileBytes("../public.der", 0);

    char* public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    int public_key_length = public_key.len;

    char* private_key_bytes = private_key.bytes;
    int private_key_length = private_key.len;

    RSA * rsa;

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    private_key_bytes = private_key.bytes;
    private_key_length = private_key.len;
    rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa = d2i_RSAPublicKey(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPublicKey(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    private_key_bytes = private_key.bytes;
    private_key_length = private_key.len;
    rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&rsa, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&rsa, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"None of the following works"*  How do you know?

Comment: Updated the question with an explanation. Why the negative vote?

Comment: If interested, you can see an example of reading an writing keys in a number of  formats using C++ at [How to generate RSA private key using openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30493975/608639) Also, you would use [d2i_X509](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/d2i_X509.html) to read an entire certificate in ASN.1/DER format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR**: `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY` and `d2i_RSAPrivateKey` should work, and do for me on Unix.

You say you want 'DER-encoded keys (PKCS#1)'.

For publickeys OpenSSL normally uses the format defined in X.509 as `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` which contains an `AlgorithmIdentifier` *plus* (edited) `BIT STRING` containing a publickey value in a structure that varies depending on the algorithm. For RSA, the algid contains an OID identifying RSA and no parameters; the algorithm-dependent structure is PKCS#1.

In contrast, OpenSSL supports two types of privatekey format: there is a 'legacy' format for each algorithm (except DH), which for RSA is PKCS#1; and a generic format defined by PKCS#8 which like SPKI consists of an `AlgorithmIdentifier` plus an algorithm-dependent privatekey value, this time in `OCTET STRING`. PKCS#8 also has an option to encrypt the key, which SPKI doesn't have or need.

Older parts of OpenSSL, including the `genrsa` and `rsa` commandline utilities, use legacy privatekey format, but SPKI publickey format which OpenSSL names PUBKEY. Thus your `rsa` commands created a publickey file readable by `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY` but not `d2i_RSAPublicKey` (which would be only the PKCS#1 part) and a privatekey file readable by `d2i_RSAPrivateKey`.

If you truly need publickey in 'bare' PKCS#1 format, the `rsa` utility has options `-RSAPublicKey_in` and `-RSAPublicKey_out` to read and write this format since 1.0.0, although documented only recently and still not in the help message. That file will be readable by `d2i_RSAPublicKey` but not `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY`.

**One possibility**: you don't mention operating system. DER files are binary, and in C to correctly handle **binary files on Windows** you must `fopen` with the `b` modifier, here you want `"rb"` for read binary. If I run your code on Unix it works, but to get correct results on Windows I must add the `b`.

Also a minor point: you talk about 'loading contents ... in char* variables'. Actually you load the file contents into memory and use a `char *` variable to point to them. Strictly speaking, OpenSSL `d2i` routines want the address of a `const unsigned char *` variable -- and your compiler should warn you about this mismatch at least if you run it in a standard-conforming mode. But C requires pointers to all `char` flavors (`signed` `unsigned` and 'plain'), with or without qualification, to have the same representation and alignment requirements, even though they aren't compatible as defined in the standard, so passing `char **` where `const unsigned char **` is expected does work.

Comment: Yes, I'm running on Windows - the "rb" flag fixed it. I did not know about the "b" flag on Windows... shame on me.

Comment: The content of this answer regarding different storage mechanisms, the sources of those operations, and the resulting APIs that allow proper reading of those keys, in particular paragraphs 2 through 5, should be the stuff of legend. If I could uptick this a hundred times I would.