# unique_ptr and OpenSSL's STACK_OF(X509)*

Tags: c++, c++11, openssl, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I use some `using` statements and `unique_ptr` to work with OpenSSL, as [suggested in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38079093/608639). Without, code becomes really ugly and I am not so much a fan of goto statements.

So far I have changed my code as far as possible. Here are examples, what I use:

```
using BIO_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIO, decltype(&::BIO_free)>;
using X509_ptr = std::unique_ptr<X509, decltype(&::X509_free)>;
using EVP_PKEY_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_PKEY, decltype(&::EVP_PKEY_free)>;
using PKCS7_ptr = std::unique_ptr<PKCS7, decltype(&::PKCS7_free)>;
...

BIO_ptr tbio(BIO_new_file(some_filename, "r"), ::BIO_free);
```

Now I have the need of a `STACK_OF(X509)` and I do not know, if this is also possible with `unique_ptr`. I am looking for something similar to below, but this is not working.

```
using STACK_OF_X509_ptr = std::unique_ptr<STACK_OF(X509), decltype(&::sk_X509_free)>;
```

I also tried the Functor:

```
struct StackX509Deleter {
    void operator()(STACK_OF(X509) *ptr) {
        sk_X509_free(ptr);
    }
};

using STACK_OF_X509_ptr = std::unique_ptr<STACK_OF(X509), StackX509Deleter>;

STACK_OF_X509_ptr chain(loadIntermediate(cert.string()));
```

The compiler accepts this and the application runs. Just one question: In other `unique_ptrs` as shown above, I always had specified a second argument, so I bet I am missing something:

```
STACK_OF_X509_ptr chain(loadIntermediate(cert.string()),  ??????);
```

How do I use C++ `unique_ptr` and OpenSSL's `STACK_OF(X509)*`?

Comment: Was there perhaps an error message? Maybe a compilable code snippet we could use to replicate?

Comment: The Deleter you're providing doesn't conform to the required Deleter prototype. You need to write a custom deallocator (a functor) that acceps `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer` as argument and invokes `sk_X509_free` internally. Then you can use `std::unique_ptr<STACK_OF(X509), your_functor_name>;`.

Comment: @jweyrich, I think, I do understand it :-) A Functor is something like operator(), is it? Do I need to write a class for it with this operator defined? Do you have an example for me? Please :-)

Comment: Can this also be done with a lambda?

Comment: @ChristianRößner: Right. A function object (or functor) is a struct/class containing a method that overrides the `()` operator. For examples, see [IntComparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) or [Accumulator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317528/298054).

Comment: @ChristianRößner - First, visit [STACK API](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API) on the OpenSSL wiki. Second, `STACK_OF` is a macro. I *believe* its type is `X509*`. You might try to use a `typedef` that gets to the underlying type. You also might using `DECLARE_STACK_OF`. (Sorry I don't have better for you. I have not used them like that before).

Comment: I "think" I just got a solution. I will edit my original post

Comment: Well done @ChristianRößner! Pretty clean solution! Now you might post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I defined a regular function:

```
void stackOfX509Deleter(STACK_OF(X509) *ptr) {
    sk_X509_free(ptr);
}
```

Then I use it in my code:

```
using STACK_OF_X509_ptr = std::unique_ptr<STACK_OF(X509),
    decltype(&stackOfX509Deleter)>;

STACK_OF_X509_ptr chain(loadIntermediate(cert.string()),
                    stackOfX509Deleter);
```

Comment: by the way: would be nice to get this done with a lambda. But this is an extra question;)