# Separating public and private keys of ECDSA keypair

Tags: c++, openssl, ecdsa, key-pair

I'm using c++ to try to generate a ECDSA key-pair following [Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography) from the OpenSSL wiki.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>

int main()
{
    EC_KEY *key;

    if(NULL == (key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1)))
        std::cout << "error on new_curve_by_name" << std::endl;

    if(1 != EC_KEY_generate_key(key)) std::cout << "error in generating keys" << std::endl;
}
```

The key pair is generated without errors, but I don't know how to extract public and private key in two different objects (EC_POINT and BIGNUM), any idea?

Comment: C++ can make it easier to use OpenSSL. You can avoid explicit calls to functions like `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free` by using `unique_ptr`. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) on the OpenSSL wiki, [unique_ptr and OpenSSL's STACK_OF(X509)*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38145761/608639), [How to get PKCS7_sign result into a char * or std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38079093/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the methods you want are:

[EC_KEY_get0_private_key](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EC_KEY_get0_private_key.html) and 
[EC_KEY_get0_public_key](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EC_KEY_get0_public_key.html)

This works for me:

```
EC_KEY* key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1);

if(!key)
{
    std::cerr << "Error creating curve key" << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if(!EC_KEY_generate_key(key))
{
    std::cerr << "Error generating curve key" << '\n';
    EC_KEY_free(key);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

BIGNUM const* prv = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(key);
if(!prv)
{
    std::cerr << "Error getting private key" << '\n';
    EC_KEY_free(key);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

std::cout << "Private key: " << prv << '\n';

EC_POINT const* pub = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(key);
if(!pub)
{
    std::cerr << "Error getting public key" << '\n';
    EC_KEY_free(key);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

std::cout << "Public key: " << pub << '\n';

// Use keys here ...

EC_KEY_free(key);
```

**NOTE:**

When using `C` libraries like this I often define a custom *smart pointer* to take care if the deletions. This makes the code less prone to memory leaks and "exception safe".

For example I would define something like this:

```
struct ec_key_dter{void operator()(EC_KEY* k)const{if(k) EC_KEY_free(k);}};
using  ec_key_uptr = std::unique_ptr<EC_KEY, ec_key_dter>;
```

And use it like this:

```
auto key = ec_key_uptr(EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1));

if(!key)
    throw std::runtime_error("Error creating curve key");

if(!EC_KEY_generate_key(key.get()))
    throw std::runtime_error("Error generating curve key");

if(!EC_KEY_check_key(key.get()))
    throw std::runtime_error("Error checking curve key");

// ... etc ...

// Do not delete the key manually!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do the following :

```
BIGNUM *privateKey;
EC_POINT *publicKey;

privateKey = BN_new();
EC_KEY_set_private_key(key, privateKey);
EC_KEY_set_public_key(key, publicKey);
```

EDIT :

These two calls will set the `privateKey` and the `publicKey` respectively.
[Open SSL Documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BN_dup.html) claims that "**destination should be a newly allocated BIGNUM obtained via a call to** `BN_new()`. **It should not have been used for other purposes or initialised in any way.**", hence i am adding the `BN_new()` call.

I don't see anything similar to create an EC_Point object( unless you use an EC_Group to create this way : `EC_POINT *EC_POINT_new(const EC_GROUP *group);`

So try this, if you still don't get it, then maybe you should look into how an EC_Point object is created correctly according to your usage.

Comment: I already tried this, but both methods generate an error. I think you need to use them only if you already own the public or private key

Comment: sorry it's not an error, they simply return 0 which is the error code

Answer (score 0):

This returns the private key as a BIGNUM

```
BIGNUM* bn = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(key);
```

For the public key not sure how to get an EC_POINT but you can get the raw bytes with something like:

```
  // first call returns length of key
  int len = i2o_ECPublicKey(key, 0);  
  std::vector<unsigned char> bytes b(len, 0);
  unsigned char* p = &b[0];
  // second call copies key into p (and returns length if successful)
  if (i2o_ECPublicKey(key, &p)) != len)
  {
    // handle error
  }
```