# How to send EVP_PKEY to other party?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes, rsa

I am struggling with the OpenSSL API for C++ at the moment. I'm using the EVP functions to generate a RSA keypair which then is used to encrypt the AES key that was used for encrypting the data (hybrid encryption).

Key generation:

```
EVP_PKEY* keypair = NULL;
EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx);
EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, 4096);
EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &keypair);
EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
```

Now I have a keypair. When Encrypting a message on my own machine via EVP_SealInit / EVP_SealUpdate / EVP_SealFinal there is no problem. Same for the decrypting process. I simply give keypair as an argument to the SealInit / OpenInit function.

But consider that I want to generate a keypair and send the public or private key as a char* over a socket to another person: how do I do that?

One way I found in the Internet is using PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY or PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey to convert the Keys to char*. When trying it seemed to work. But I'm still not 100% sure. So Please look at my code and tell me if those functions are the way to go:

```
unsigned char* publicKey;
BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio, keypair);
RSAmakeString(&publicKey, bio);

unsigned char* privateKey;
BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(bio, keypair, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
RSAmakeString(&privateKey, bio);
```

The other thing is how do I convert the char* back to EVP_PKEY*? Are there any functions? Because if I want to use SealInit with my public Key on another computer I have to convert it back from a char* to an EVP_PKEY*, so I can use it in the function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But consider that I want to generate a keypair and send the public or private key as a char* over a socket to another person: how do I do that?

You need something for serialization and wire formats or a presentation format. Your public key and encrypted messages will likely have `0` characters, which appear as embedded `NULL`. So you need to have both a buffer and explicit length .

Use Google's [ProtocolBuffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), [Binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/), or even ASN.1/DER encoding. I think Google's `ProtocolBuffers` are message oriented, so they won't return a message until the complete message is available.

You could also Hex, Base32 or Base64 encode it. But you still need to communicate a length so the receiving party knows they got the whole message. On a local LAN you will probably never experience a problem. Over the Internet you will probably get occasional failures as your perform short reads on occasion.

Your thoughts on `PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY` are effectively Base64 encoding the key, so it suffers the same potential problem as Hex, Base32 or Base64 encoding.

---

> how do I convert the char* back to EVP_PKEY

Well, you probably won't be using a `char*` based on your changes above. Once you refine the design, you should probably ask a new question.

But at the moment, and given you saved the key with `PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY` and `PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey`, then you would use `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY` or `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey`, respectively. Also see OpenSSL's [`PEM` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY.html).

---

Related to C++, here are some tricks when working with OpenSSL. If you are using C++11, then `unique_ptr` really makes it easy to work with some OpenSSL objects.

- [unique_ptr and OpenSSL's STACK_OF(X509)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38145761/608639)
- [How to get PKCS7_sign result into a char * or std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38077226/608639)
- [Non-printable character after generating random n-byte Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38356835/608639)
- [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) on the OpenSSL wiki

Comment: So when I use PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY to convert the Public Key to a char* can't I just add the size of itself in front of it? This way the receiver would know the size of the char* and can receive until it got everything. If an error occurs it just requests the Key again. Or does this not work?