# OpenSSL PEM_read_RSAPublicKey and PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY crashes the program

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I have a public key in the form of

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIB...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

that was created using OpenSSL. I attempt to load it into memory like such:

```
FILE* file = fopen("public.pem","r");
if (file != nullptr)
{
   //This can be changed to this for the same results:
   //RSA* rsa = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(file, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
   RSA* rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
   //etc...
}
```

Whenever it gets to the RSA* rsa =... line the program crashes. I have seen the other post for this and (as you can see) I have tried it the solution and it doesn't work.

I have tried using the BIO versions and the program does not crash but I do get the error "no start line".

Any ideas as to what can be causing this?

Comment: I think  that you need to point to valid structures where data will be read to instead of using nullptr.

Comment: Maybe the method PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY shouldn't be given `nullptr`s?

Comment: I have tried: if (!PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, &rsa, nullptr, nullptr)) (where rsa was initialized using RSA_new()) and it still crashes. The last two fields are just password fields if you use a password. The second to last is a callback function pointer to find the password and the last one is a void* that is pointing to a char*. Mine does have a password but using (void*)password for the last parameter does not help.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RSA* rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
> ```

The second argument cannot be NULL. That's causing your crash. In addition, its a pointer-to-a-pointer (double indirection). Also see the [`PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY.html).

Maybe you should use something like:

```
RSA* t = RSA_new();
RSA* rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, &t, nullptr, nullptr);
```

The data may be malformed, and it could be causing an unexpected crash. If you provide real data, then we can usually cross-check it. In the absence of real data, we can't really say.

You might also want to visit [How to generate RSA private key using openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493975/608639). It shows you several RSA output formats. It also shows you how to manage OpenSSL resources using C++.

Comment: I tried your option and it still crashed. I switched to using file BIOs instead and that worked. I've had issues with OpenSSL and FILE before, so idk what's going on. Thanks for the input :)