# What does cb_arg in old versions of OpenSSL mean?

Tags: c, openssl

I installed archaic `OpenSSL_0_9_6-beta3` version of OpenSSL. The function `RSA_generate_key` is defined in there as follows:

```
RSA * RSA_generate_key(int bits, unsigned long e,void (*callback)(int,int,void *),void *cb_arg)
```

This is my test code:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int main(){

    unsigned long   e = RSA_F4;

    RSA *r = RSA_generate_key(512, e, NULL, NULL);
    const BIGNUM *n = r->n;
    BN_print_fp(stdout, n);
    RSA_free(r);

    return  0;
}
```

When I run it, it just loops forever. When run under Valgrind I can see why:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)
```

I guess that is because I don't understand what the function signature really means and I am passing incorrect parameters into it - there have been problems with methods looping when being fed incorrect parameters since forever in OpenSSL. That is why I came here to ask you if you understand the function signature, because I can't find any guides on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does cb_arg in old versions of OpenSSL mean?
>       RSA_generate_key(int bits, unsigned long e,void (*callback)(int,int,void *),void *cb_arg)

Its a function callback. It allows you to implement a progress bar during RSA key generation because the operation can take a long time.

`RSA_generate_key` is deprecated. You should use `RSA_generate_key_ex` instead.

Also see [How to generate RSA private key using openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927164/608639) on Stack Overflow, [`RSA_generate_key` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html) and [`RSA_generate_key_ex` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/RSA_generate_key_ex.html).

---

> ```
> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)
> ```

You should provide the context of the finding. Also, be sure to compile OpenSSL and your program with `-O1`. If optimizations are too high, then Valgrind generates false positives. Also see [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: -O1 changes nothing. I was told there might be a problem with not seeding the random number generator.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton - Did you recompile OpenSSL too? If you got it from a distro, then its compiled at `-O3`.